# Youtube AS3 API Crossdomain

Tags: actionscript-3, cross-domain, youtube-api

I'm trying to use Youtube AS3 API to display some Youtube videos into my flash movie, but when I upload it to my own server, the browser is showing me this message:

> **Error #2044**: SecurityErrorEvent: text=Error #2121: **Sandbox Security
>   Violation**: http://***/magicbook.swf?user=25&id=2283:
>   http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3 can't access to.

I've already added my `Security.allowDomain` policies in order to allow access between both servers. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
class YoutubePlayer extends Sprite {

    private var player:Object;
    private var loader:Loader;
    private var _videoID:String;

    public function YoutubePlayer(videoID:String) {

        Security.allowInsecureDomain("*");
        Security.allowDomain("*");          

        //loader = addChild(new Loader()) as Loader;
        loader = new Loader();
        loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onLoaderInit, false, 0, true);
        loader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3"));
        _videoID = videoID;
    }

    private function onLoaderInit(event:Event):void {
        player = loader.content;
        player.addEventListener("onReady", onPlayerReady);
    }
    private function onPlayerReady(event:Event):void {
        player.setSize(320, 180);
        player.cueVideoByUrl("http://www.youtube.com/v/"+_videoID,0);
        player.addEventListener("onError",seeError);
        this.addChild(loader);
    }

    private function seeError(event:Event):void{
        trace("error");
    }

    public function playYoutube():void{
        player.playVideo();
    }

    public function stopYoutube():void{
        player.stopVideo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that there's an "import flash.system.Security" at the top.

My own very similar code works fine, and the only major differences are:

- I add the loader to the stage in the INIT event handler (not before it has loaded)
- For some reason I've got Security.allowDomain("*") and Security.allowDomain("www.youtube.com") - I'm not certain why (it could be a bug but can't test right now)

Hopefully those differences help.. I'm not really a flash/actionscript expert.